# Bash threading: wait for all job threads to finish doesn't work?

Tags: bash, multithreading

I'm writing a little script, that will create archives in main thread and after each archive is complete, a new thread would be created by calling function that would take care of uploading these archives. The reason I want uploading to be done in background is so that another archive could be created while the previous archives are being uploaded.

The problem I'm having is at the very end of the script. That is, main thread don't wait for all uploading threads to finish before exiting. Look at the following simplified script (I removed/changed parts of the code not related to the problem)

```
function func {
for files in /home/somewhere/
  do
    echo "Uploading $1" &
  done
wait
}

find /home/some/path -type f | while read filename ; do
  echo "Creating archive of $filename"
  func $somevariable &
done

wait
```

Everything is executing very nicely until the last archive is created, then the script ends before all `func` threads finish, leaving many files not uploaded.

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: @Andrew: what OS are you using?  I'm aware of some Solaris builds that have a wait bug just like this.

Comment: @martin clayton: I'm using Ubuntu Server 9.10

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update: good points in the comment.

So, on a second look, it turns out the problem is the subshell that is created by the pipe to the loop. It's a good way to structure the script but *you need to do the final wait in the shell that spun off the background tasks.*

So do something like this:

```
find /home/some/path -type f | (while read filename; do
    echo "Creating archive of $filename"
    func $somevariable &
  done
  wait
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I remove `&` from `function func` it would wait for the func to complete, no? Also, I have upload function in loop, so that 4 archives are being uploaded at once. For that I need that loop to continue even after executing upload commands. EDIT: I have `wait` in shell function as well.

Comment: Thanks again for update :) I *think* that did the trick. I'll do some more tests.

Answer (score 7):

Tricky! The problem is that this block

```
find /home/some/path -type f | while read filename ; do
  ...
done
```

Creates a subshell. The func $somevariable jobs are created in that subshell. The parent shell sees that all the background jobs *it* created have finished, it doesn't keep track of background jobs created by subshells it spawned.

The easiest fix is to create your background jobs from the parent shell instead. You can avoid creating a subshell by not using a pipe:

```
while read filename ; do
  ...
done < <(find /home/some/path -type f)
```

Well, that creates *a* subshell---for the find---but the while block is no longer in a subshell.

Note that the above works only under bash. (Don't know about ksh or zsh, perhaps it works there too. But it won't work under ash and other sh derivatives.)

Answer (score 4):

If you execute `wait` with no arguments, it is supposed to wait for currently active child processes to complete.

The problem is likely to be that "all currently active child processes" does not mean what you think it means in this context.  In particular, if you create pipelines in a subshell it is not entirely clear if they would be waited for in the parent shell.

I suspect that `wait` actually only waits for processes / pipelines that show up in the output of `jobs`.  Try some experiments ...

A possible alternative may be to capture the child process ids and do a `wait n` call for each id.

Answer (score -1):

You could loop until the `jobs` command returns nothing as an alternative method.

Answer (score -2):

You could try this script. It does precisely that. 
https://github.com/pabloniklas/BASH/blob/master/lib_cpu.sh